# django-admin.py startproject mysite not working python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I've read a ton of articles about adding things to the windows PATH variable but none of them have worked so far. I also read about editing regedit and finding some things, however I was unable to find what people were referring to.

So I'm trying to run:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Previously it would open a window asking me which program to open the file with. I stupidly added it to python.exe, however I think this is now causing more problems as when I run the above command it opens a little black windows then vanishes as Python.exe now tries to open the file. But I think this could be preventing the command working?

It certainly isn't creating anything...

Would this indeed cause problems, or are things just as broke as previously? Really need some help here, it's very frustrating that nothing seems to get it working. Is there is additional information you need, please let me know.

Comment: Give us some specific info. What you get when you run `python.exe django-admin.py startproject mysite `?

Answer (score 1):

I think your system is not finding the file django-admin.py. Use cmd and navigate to the directory that contains this file and try to execute the command from there:

```
python django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

If it works, I recommend you to create an environment variable (e.g. DJANGO_ADMIN) to point do django-admin.py so you can execute the command below from anywhere:

```
python %DJANGO_ADMIN% startproject mysite
```

**EDIT:**

Creating an environment variable on **Windows XP**:

1. Open System in Control Panel.
2. On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables, then click the name of the user variable or system variable you want to change, as follows. Click 'New' to add a new variable name and value.

Creating an environment variable on **Windows 7**:

1. Open the Start Menu and right click on Computer. Select Properties.
2. Select Advanced system settings.
3. In the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables.
4. Select 'New'.

Creating an environment variable on **Windows 8**:

Start -> All Apps -> Control panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables.

Comment: How would i create an environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can Follow @AmauryMedeiros answer or you can set a path to system environment variable to `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

It works...